# 'get_data' object has no attribute 'set_index'

Tags: python

I was trying to run this code to generate a heatmap, but I keep getting this error, any suggestion

```
from bioinfokit import analys, visuz
# load dataset as pandas dataframe
path = '/Users/ss/Desktop/test/Name.csv'
df = analys.get_data('path')

# set radiomics features as index
df = df.set_index(df.columns[0])
df.head(2)

visuz.gene_exp.hmap(df=df, rowclus=False, colclus=False, dim=(3, 6), tickfont=(6, 4))
```

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
5
6 # set Radiomics features as index
----> 7 df = df.set_index(df.columns[0])
8 df.head(2)
9

AttributeError: 'get_data' object has no attribute 'set_index'

Comment: Try to change get_data('path') to get_data(path)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your traceback, either `analys.get_data(...)` isn't the object you think it is, or it is the object you think it is doesn't support `set_index`.

Looking at the [docs](https://github.com/reneshbedre/bioinfokit/blob/9a6cd55c51d4c3822d93df2f88040a03d66c38bd/bioinfokit/tests/test_analys.py#L9) for `get_data`, an appropriate fix would probably be:

```
df = analys.get_data(path).data
```